# Redirecionar para Tab especifica

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

Bom dia pessoal, tenho uma aba onde possuo um form que é enviado via Ajax para meu controller e quero que depois da resposta do Ajax a pessoa seja redirecionada para outra tab depois de recarregar a pagina, preciso que al clicar em calculate a pessoa vá para Analysis Results alguém pode me dar uma luz?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da TAB:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs border-0 pt-5 data pt-sm-5 pt-md-1 mt-4 justify-content-center position-fixed mt-md-2 col-sm-12 col-md-12 ml-0 " style="z-index:1;font-size:100%;" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item data active">
        <a class="nav-link data active " id="data" data-toggle="tab" href="#DataInput" role="tab" aria-controls="Data Input" aria-selected="true">Data Input &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class=" bg-light ">
        <input class="button" onclick="calculate()" type="submit" name="" 
     value="Calculate" style="margin-top:5px;">&nbsp;
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item analise ">
        <a class="nav-link  analise" id="analise" data-toggle="tab" 
       href="#Analise" role="tab" aria-controls="Analysis Results " aria- 
       selected="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Analysis Results 
      &nbsp; </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link " id="graphs" data-toggle="tab" href="#Graficos" 
      role="tab" aria-controls="Analysis Results " aria-selected="true"><i 
       class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Graph &nbsp; </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Saudações Jeison. Você deve ter percebido que o [pt.so] segue a estrutura de perguntas e respostas em que há uma distinção bem clara entre ambas. O que é pergunta fica na pergunta, o que é resposta fica na resposta. Então, por favor, evite colocar a solução na pergunta. Se conseguiu resolver o problema e a solução ainda não foi postada por outro usuário, você pode responder colocando-a. [Não é errado responder sua própria pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meu Problema foi solucionado da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="#" id="meuElemento" onclick="funcao('minha string')">clique aqui.</a>

    <script>
        function funcao(string) {
            alert(string)
        }
        document.getElementById("meuElemento").click();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o `window.location.href = "http://seusite.com";`

Apos a resposta do seu Ajax

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito mas tenta isso:
Na parte `.done(...` do metodo ajax depois que você redireciona para essa pagina.

```
if ($('#tabCalc').hasClass('show')) { // verifica se a tab esta sendo 
mostrada
  $('#tabCalc').removeClass('show'); // remove a class show da tab
  $('#tabAna').addClass('show');     // add Class show na tab desejada
}
// ou você pode tentar assim mais simples poem ao meu ver uma forma 
ruim ou vc verifica todas com if acimae faz isso :D
  $('#tab1').removeClass('show');
  $('#tab2').removeClass('show');
  $('#tab3').removeClass('show');
  $('#tab4').removeClass('show');
  $('#tabDesejada').addClass('show');
```

após editar a pergunta novas opções podem ser vistas como no código abaixo:

```
// Após o retorno do método Ajax para redirecionar para o local da pagina desejado
window.location.href = "http://index.html#Analise"; 
// ou forçar um click no elemando analise que tbm o levará para o local desejado
document.getElementById('analise').click();
```

Provavelmente exitem formas melhores para se fazer isto. 
espero que isto lhe ajude agora. pois pelo que entendi da pergunta erá isso que você queria

Comment: não funcionou, vou editar e deixar o codigo da tab, talvez ajude

Comment: vc quer apenas setar a tab selecionada ou o conteúdo dela tbm?

Comment: tenta> window.location.href = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com#Analise"; <
ps: desculpa isso provavelmente não irá funciona talvez, porem se vc quer que ele seja redirecionado para o aparte do conteúdo que está na pagina isso certamente servira se o conteúdo não estiver oculto. agora se o conteúdo estiver o culto e vc estiver trabalhando com 'tabs' e o click na 'Analise Result' apenas vá para o conteúdo vc pode tentar tbm > document.getElementById('analise').click(); <;

Comment: modifique tbm o aria-controls="Analysis Results" dos gráficos para o nome certoestá com o mesmo da Analise Result. vo editar a resposta. tbm

Comment: consegui resolver simulando um click com java Script, vou atualizar pra deixar registrado, obg pela ajuda.

Comment: Que bom :D
desculpa não ter a melhor método, para lhe ajudar .